# Flutter Foreground Service not working when app is closed by pressing back button

Tags: firebase, flutter, geolocation, foreground-service

I am developing a location app where in I have created a foreground service using flutter foreground service plugin.

Foreground service works fine till app is open. However, when I close the app by clicking back button, my foreground call back function starts giving below error.

W/FlutterJNI(11912): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: com.changjoopark.flutter_foreground_plugin/callback. Response ID: 0